# Script out of range when trying to run a login.asp from a computer on the network

Tags: asp-classic

So i have this login script that will open on the machine its located on but if i try to run from my machine on the same network and subnet i get the below error log message.
And

> Server Error 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the
>   resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
>
> GET /isite/login.asp
>   |22|800a0009|Subscript_out_of_range:*'[number:*-1]' 80 - 172.17.11.212
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:31.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/31.0
>   500 0 0 50

```
<!-- CENTER COLUMN BEGINS HERE -->     
<%
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------
'This page is used to allow users to login to the intranet page.  
'If no attempt at logging in has been made, the section below will run.
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 if request.querystring("action") = "" then

  full_username = Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")
  'response.write full_username
  'response.End()
  username = Split(full_username,"\")
  Dim uservalid
  uservalid = "false"
  SQLgetallusers = "SELECT * FROM users"
  rs.Open SQLgetallusers, Conn
    Do while not rs.EOF
      If LCase(rs("userid")) = LCase(username(ubound(username))) then
        uservalid = "true"
      End if
      rs.MoveNext
    Loop
  rs.Close

  If uservalid = "true" then
    response.cookies("user") = LCase(username(ubound(username)))
    Response.Cookies ("user").Expires = DATE + 365
    response.redirect("index.asp")
  Else
  End if
%> 
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" align="center">
       <tr> 
        <td class="titleheader">Please Login</td>
       </tr>
       <tr> 
        <td class="maintext">
          <table width="100%" border=0 cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <td width="100%" align="center">You do not have access to this resource.<br>
              <br>
              Please contact the Service Desk for access.
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
<%
  else

'If the user has made an attempt at logging in, the following scripts will run
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'This creates a recordset with all the users in it which will allow us to check for usernames against passwords.
SQLgetaccount = "SELECT * FROM users"
rs.Open SQLgetaccount, Conn

  Do while not rs.EOF
    'If the username entered in the login page and the password entered in the login page both correspond to their
    'database equivalents, then the user cookie is created with an expiry of 1 year and the user is redirected to index.asp
    if rs("userid") = request.form("user_name") AND rs("password") = request.form("user_pass") then
      Response.Cookies ("user") = rs("userid")
      Response.Cookies ("user").Expires = DATE + 365
      response.redirect("index.asp")
    end if
    rs.MoveNext
  Loop
rs.Close
'If the username and password are incorrect, the following script is run
%>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" align="center">
       <tr> 
        <td class="titleheader">Please Login</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="maintext"><form method=post action="login.asp?action=login">
          <table width="100%" border=0 cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <td colspan=2 align="center" class="maintext"><p style=" color: red "><strong>Invalid Login details</strong></p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width=50% align="right" class="maintext">Username: </td>
              <td width=50% align="left" class="maintext"><input type="text" class="maintext" name="user_name"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width=50% align="right" class="maintext">Password: </td>
              <td width=50% align="left" class="maintext"><input type="password" class="maintext" name="user_pass"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan=2 align="center"><input type="submit" value="Log In"></td>
            </tr>
          </table></form>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
<%
  end if
%>
<!-- CENTER COLUMN ENDS HERE -->

<!--#include file="footer.inc"-->
```

Comment: You must consider the specific case where "\" is not contained in username

Comment: Have you ensured that the application is set-up properly in IIS? Also, which version of IIS are you running, and, if it's Windows Vista or above, have you got the Classic ASP plugin installed for IIS?